# google photos crashing when selecting from image chooser

Tags: android, google-photos

When choosing google photos from image chooser it is opening but immediately it is crashing. it is happening only in lenovo k8.

i tried to find why it is crashing but failed.

here is the crash report what i'm getting

```
 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 11675 (RenderThread)
 I/crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned
 I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 11588
 I/crash_dump64: performing dump of process 11588 (target tid = 11675)
 A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'lenovo/manning_retail/manning:8.0.0/OMB27.43-67/73:user/release-keys'
 A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
 A/DEBUG: pid: 11588, tid: 11675, name: RenderThread  >>> com.google.android.apps.photos <<<
 A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
 A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference

 E/libPerfService: Could not open '/proc/driver/thermal/ta_fg_pid'
E/libPerfService: error : 2, No such file or directory
E/ActivityManager: Found activity ActivityRecord{5561e27 u0 com.google.android.apps.photos/.picker.external.ExternalPickerActivity t-1 f} in proc activity list using null instead of expected ProcessRecord{abb7d68 11588:com.google.android.apps.photos/u0a104}
I/BufferQueueConsumer: [ActionableToast:825225c#0](this:0x7072ba1000,id:5379,api:1,p:11588,c:-1) disconnect(C)
E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/11588/oom_score_adj; errno=22
I/BufferQueueConsumer: [com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.apps.photos.picker.external.ExternalPickerActivity#0](this:0x7072a60800,id:5378,api:1,p:11588,c:-1) disconnect(C)
V/WindowManager: findFocusedWindow: No focusable windows.
E/ProfileFrag: onActivityResult requestCode 100
E/ProfileFrag: onActivityResult resultCode 0
E/ProfileFrag: onActivityResult data null
D/ProcSpeedReader: Failed to read freq stats from null
I/ActivityManager: Killing 11588:com.google.android.apps.photos/u0a104 (adj 199): crash
```

please help me to solve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like it is a google photo problem, not your

Comment: thanks for reply, ya but when i'm opening google photos its opening and working but when i'm choosing from image chooser then it is crashing..

Comment: ok, there is likely a problem in google photos when it is opened to choose photo.

Comment: i've tested in couple of mobiles but it is happening in lenevo k8 only..